# Eclipse keeps wrapping my lines even though I have taken measures to prevent this

Tags: java, eclipse, word-wrap

I'm using windows 7 64 bit with 32 bit JDK 1.7, Eclipse Indigo

I have a wide screen and I think its hard to read functionality quickly from wrapped lines. I would like Eclipse to do the indentation correction for me but I dislike the wrapping functionality and would like to turn it off.

So here's what I have done:

Window>Preferences>Java>Code Style>Formatter:

created a profile with my name then clicked "Edit..." button.

"Line Wrapping" Tab I have the following:

Maximum line width: 200
Default indentation for wrapped lines: 2
Default indentation for array initializers: 2
Never join already wrapped lines: not checked
Prefer wrapping outer expressions (keep nested expressions on one line): not checked

Every policy in the list that comes below is set to: Do not wrap.

When pressing Ctrl+Shift+F my lines are wrapped. The longest line I can find has 109 characters in it.

Can someone help me find what I have done wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, your project does not have specific formatting enabled?

Comment: thank you very much! I should have asked earlier. Wondering how I can give you credit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the following items:

- Correct Profile is selected;
- Comments has its own `Line Width` configuration;
- A settings specific for project is overwriting the Workspace settings. (`Project Properties` > `Java Code Style` > `Formatter`)